# Display stays black after wakeup from suspend

Tags: display, screen, suspend, resume, wakeup

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 on a 305u1a Samsung netbook with Radeon HD 6320 graphics.
After suspend, my display stays black. The fans are starting and the harddrive-indication-light is working as well, so the system is waking up. The backlight doesn't wake up. I'm searching for 3 days and trying out several manuals, but its still not working.

thanks for your help!

Comment: I've seen this happen on 2 different laptops. After some time, usually about 2-5 minutes, the screen would flicker to life and I would be presented with the unlock prompt. See if waiting for a while will work.

Comment: Does not work. Since I updated the Kernel to 3.00.... suspend does not work...

Comment: I may have a similar problem, on my Samsung N310 with Ubuntu 12.04 beta. When I leave my computer for a while and it goes to suspend, I can't get it to resume even though the indicators are lit. But I can suspend from the cog menu and resume afterwards. Is your problem only related to the power management too?

Comment: Having the same problem on Samsung Series 9(B)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for deletion. Thanks!